# Custom listview in fragment - null pointer exceptions

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-listview, nullpointerexception

i'm new to the "whole fragments" concept and i need some help.

I want to use custom listview in fragment, my code was working fine in Activity, but implementation in fragment is quite a pain. I am getting 2 null exceptions and i cant find out where.

I also have very basic question, what context should i use in the fragment, from fragment activity or fragment itself?

Here is my fragment code

```
public class NewsFeed extends Fragment {

List<NewsFeedList> fr_ne_list = new ArrayList<NewsFeedList>();
Context ctx;
ListView list;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_news_feed, container, false);
    list=(ListView)v.findViewById(R.id.listViewNewsFeedFriend);
    return v;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if(isAdded()) {
        ctx=getActivity();
        napolniseznamFriendList();
        /*"at com.osembitdesign.faceit.NewsFeed.onCreate(NewsFeed.java:49)"*/
        fillNewsFeedListView(fr_ne_list);
    }

}

//filling custom listview
private void fillNewsFeedListView(List<NewsFeedList> elem) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ArrayAdapter<NewsFeedList> adapter = new MyListAdapter(ctx,R.layout.news_feed_list_item, elem);

    /*"at com.osembitdesign.faceit.NewsFeed.fillNewsFeedListView(NewsFeed.java:58)"*/
    list.setAdapter(adapter);

}


private class MyListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<NewsFeedList> {
    public MyListAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    private List<NewsFeedList> element;

    public MyListAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<NewsFeedList> items) {
        super(context, resource, items);
        this.element = items;

    }

    @Override
    public View getView...
}
//adding items to my (Array)List

private void napolniseznamFriendList() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    fr_ne_list.add(new NewsFeedList("xxxx", "xxxx","xxxx",R.drawable.ic_action_search));
    fr_ne_list.add(new NewsFeedList("xxx", "xx","xxx",R.drawable.ic_action_search));
}
```

}

Error

```
03-13 21:26:21.512  24416-24416/ E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.NewsFeed.fillNewsFeedListView(NewsFeed.java:58)
            at com.NewsFeed.onCreate(NewsFeed.java:49)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Review the [Fragment lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html). `onCreate()` is always called before `onCreateView()`.

This means `list` will always be null when `fillNewsFeedListView()` is called from `onCreate()`.

Instead move the conditional statement from `onCreate()` to `onViewCreated()`. You could move it directly to `onCreateView()` but it's best to keep unrelated logic separated.

> I also have very basic question, what context should i use in the
>   fragment, from fragment activity or fragment itself?

`Fragment`s aren't `Context`s. Use `getActivity()`, it is there for a reason.

Comment: Thank you! Like you said i just moved conditional statement to onViewCreated() and it worked like a charm!

Comment: can u help me here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41938475/empty-custom-listview-in-fragment-on-back-tab

Answer (score 0):

Heres some code which I use in one of my apps. It uses a grid view which you can replace with a listview if you want. Will still work!

Fragment:

```
public class GalleryScreenFragment extends MyFragment{

private GalleryScreenGridAdapter mAdapter;
private GridView mGridView;
private boolean mActionMode = false;
private ImageButton mHomeButton,mBackButton,mDeleteButton, mShareButton;
private Animation mFadeInAnimation;
private Context mContext;
private OnGalleryItemSelectedListener mListener = mTempListener;

public GalleryScreenFragment(){
    if(null == Data.imagePathList)
        FileIO.readImageTasks();
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    if (activity instanceof OnGalleryItemSelectedListener) {
        mListener = (OnGalleryItemSelectedListener) activity;
        mContext = activity;
    }
    else{
        throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
            + " must implemenet GalleryScreenFragment.OnGalleryItemSelectedListener");
    }
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    mListener = mTempListener;
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    RelativeLayout relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_gallery_screen_main, null);
    mGridView = (GridView) relativeLayout.findViewById(R.id.gridview);
    mGridView.setEmptyView(relativeLayout.findViewById(R.id.emptyGridView));

    mHomeButton = (ImageButton) relativeLayout.findViewById(R.id.homeButton);
    mHomeButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mListener.onGalleryHomeButtonPressed();
        }
    });

    mShareButton = (ImageButton) relativeLayout.findViewById(R.id.shareButton);
    mShareButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        }
    });

    mBackButton = (ImageButton) relativeLayout.findViewById(R.id.backButton);
    mBackButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        }
    });

    mDeleteButton = (ImageButton) relativeLayout.findViewById(R.id.deleteButton);
    mDeleteButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        }
    });

    mAdapter = new GalleryScreenGridAdapter(mContext);
    mGridView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    mGridView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);

    mGridView.setOnScrollListener(new PauseOnScrollListener(ImageLoader.getInstance(), true, false));

    mFadeInAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(mContext, R.anim.fade_in);

    return relativeLayout;
}
}
```

Activity:

```
public class GalleryScreenActivity extends MyFragmentActivity implements OnGalleryItemSelectedListener{

private boolean mSelectionMode = false;
private GalleryScreenFragment mGalleryScreenFragment;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
    super.onCreate(bundle);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_gallery_screen_content_frame);

    mGalleryScreenFragment = (GalleryScreenFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.mainFragment);
}
}
```

Adapter:

```
public class GalleryScreenGridAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements BitmapProcessor{
private LayoutInflater inflater;
private Context mContext;
private DisplayImageOptions mOptions;
private ImageLoader mImageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();

public GalleryScreenGridAdapter(Context context){
    mContext = context;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService( Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE );
    mOptions = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
    .imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.EXACTLY)
    .bitmapConfig(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565)
    .preProcessor(this)
    .cacheInMemory(true)
    .resetViewBeforeLoading(true)
    .build();
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return (null == Data.imagePathList) ? 0 : Data.imagePathList.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final GridObject object = Data.imagePathList.get(position);

    final GalleryScreenGridItem view = (GalleryScreenGridItem) inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_gallery_screen_grid_item_layout, null);

    final ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.image);

    imageView.setImageBitmap(null);
    view.setChecked(false);

    mImageLoader.loadImage(object.getUrl(), new ImageSize(200, 200), mOptions, new SimpleImageLoadingListener(){

        @Override
        public void onLoadingFailed(String imageUri, View view, FailReason failReason) {
            imageView.setImageResource(android.R.drawable.ic_delete);
        }

        @Override
        public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View tempView, Bitmap loadedImage) {
            view.setChecked(object.getState());
            imageView.setImageBitmap(loadedImage);
            AlphaAnimation fadeImage = new AlphaAnimation(0, 1);
            fadeImage.setDuration(100);
            fadeImage.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
            imageView.startAnimation(fadeImage);
        }
    }, Data.imagePathList.get(position).getPictureType());
    return view;
}
}
```

Do let me know if you need any more help. It uses a fragment inside an activity. The fragment has a gridview which is populated by the adapter. Just replace the gridview with the listview and the getview of the adapter with your own code and you are good to go.

Comment: Thank you for your fast response and with code example. I'm sure somebody will use it.